# How do you set the default page in WordPress?

Tags: pages, configuration, customization

Assuming I have a page with the URL `http://papermepress.com?page_id=2` that I want to set as the default, what do I need to do so that when a user types in just `http://papermepress.com` they see that page?

Is it a simple configuration option or do I need a plugin of some sort?

Comment: what about my imaginings editor?  are they of no importance?....just kidding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your dashboard, visit `Settings > Reading` and select and for the first option, `Front page displays` select `A static page (select below)` and then select that specific page (and then another page you create for your posts to show up on if you would like).

Comment: Yes.  Not another plugin!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin for this - simply log in to your wordpress admin console, select SETTINGS, then select READING option and then choose "front page displays" - "a static page" and select the page you want to be displayed

Comment: Thanks...but Zach beat you to it.